# How can I classify images as "normal" or "lesions" using SVM?

Tags: classification, matlab, svm

I want to classify images as "normal" or "lesions", and then rate the images in the lesions category from mild and severe.
This classification would be based on edge, color and texture features.
For this concept I want to use a binary SVM classifier using threefold cross validation, in Matlab.
Where do I start?

Comment: Down voters: please provide constructive criticism on how to improve the question. @user1581472: you might get a better response if you provide a bit more detail, for example, some example images might help. Also, this site isn't about "sending codes" - it's for asking advice on how to do something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be to examine your data thoroughly before attempting to classify.

Try doing some exploratory analysis: calculate some standard features (based on edge, texture and colour as you say), then examine if those features can distinguish between your two classes (*normal* or *lesion*).
Matlab's Bioinformatics toolbox provides decent SVM functions (`svmtrain` and `svmclassify`), to start, try classifying your features using default hyperparameters (C=1, sigma=1). Once you have gotten to grips with that, you can investigate using feature selection methods and nested cross validation to improve your performance  estimates.